# How to get angular-translate in separate files

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I'm currently trying to apply angular-translate to my project.
The problem with this is that I don't want my app.js to be filled with translations, I'd rather have it in separate files in a translation folder.

My project structure looks something like this:

```
wwwroot
-- css
-- images
-- js
 --- controllers
 --- directives
 --- filters
 --- services
 --- app.js
-- resources
 --- locale-nl.json
 --- translate.js
-- views
```

My app.js looks simular to this:

```
angular.module('testApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate', 'angular-loading-bar', 'smart-table', 'pascalprecht.translate']);
```

My translate.js file looks like this:

```
angular.module("testApp").config([
    "$translateProvider", function ($translateProvider) {
        $translateProvider.useLocalStorage();
        $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
            prefix: "resources/locale-",
            suffix: ".json"
        });
        $translateProvider.preferredLanguage("nl");
    }
]);
```

The locale-nl.json looks like this:

```
{
  "FOO": "This is a paragraph",
  "TITLE": "Helloooo"
}
```

In my main.html I have a normal translation value:

```
{{ 'TITLE' | translate }}
```

and in my mainController I have this:

```
"use strict";

angular.module("testApp")
    .controller("MainController", function ($scope, $translate, userRole) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.role = userRole;
        console.log(vm.role);
    });
```

But nothing seems to get translated and it doesn't look in different files.

Comment: I an using the `$translatePartialLoader` so not exactly the same thing, but in the file I can use `folder/fileBegining-{lang}.json` and it replaces `{lang}`automatically.
Note that the language can be in the locale (ex: `en_GB` syntax)

Comment: Would it be possible to show me a bit of code how to get this going? And is there another difference between my technique except of having a variable in my json url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my gulp file I included all my `.js` files from my js folder. The translate.js was located outside my js folder. 
I moved the translation.js inside my js folder and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Add `registerAvailableLanguageKeys` to your code, according to the language key that is declared for each static file:

```
angular.module("testApp").config([
    "$translateProvider", function ($translateProvider) {
        $translateProvider.useLocalStorage();
        $translateProvider.registerAvailableLanguageKeys(['en', 'de', 'nl',    
        etc..]);
        $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
            prefix: "resources/locale-",
            suffix: ".json"
        });
        $translateProvider.preferredLanguage("nl");
    }
]);
```

Comment: Add this where? should something else be removed? It will be clearer if you'll include a complete function with that line in it. that way, no one would have to guess what you meant

Comment: I've tried your solution, but for some reason my words stil don't get translated. I don't get any error messages either

Comment: can you show in code your usage of `$translateLocalStorage`?